# Regroup the data in one dataframe using the information from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, mask

I have the following two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df_two = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'March', 'March'],
                       'B': ['Feb', 'Feb', 'March', 'March', 'Jan', 'Jan'],
                       'C': ['March', 'March', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb']},
                      index=[datetime(2020, 1, 1), datetime(2020, 1, 2),
                             datetime(2020, 1, 3), datetime(2020, 1, 4),
                             datetime(2020, 1, 5), datetime(2020, 1,6)] )

df_one = pd.DataFrame({'series_one': [2, 5, 16, 17, 88, 89],
                       'series_two': [12, 15, 86, 87, 8, 9],
                       'series_three': [82, 85, 6, 7, 18, 19]},
                      index=[datetime(2020, 1, 1), datetime(2020, 1, 2),
                             datetime(2020, 1, 3), datetime(2020, 1, 4),
                             datetime(2020, 1, 5), datetime(2020, 1, 6)])
```

which look the like this:

```
df_one
            series_one  series_two  series_three
2020-01-01           2          12            82
2020-01-02           5          15            85
2020-01-03          16          86             6
2020-01-04          17          87             7
2020-01-05          88           8            18
2020-01-06          89           9            19
```

and

```
df_two
                A      B      C
2020-01-01    Jan    Feb  March
2020-01-02    Jan    Feb  March
2020-01-03    Feb  March    Jan
2020-01-04    Feb  March    Jan
2020-01-05  March    Jan    Feb
2020-01-06  March    Jan    Feb
```

I would like to use the information of the two dataframes and get the following view:

```
            Jan  Feb  March
2020-01-01    2   12     82
2020-01-02    5   15     85
2020-01-03    6   16     86
2020-01-04    7   17     87
2020-01-05   88   18     88
2020-01-06   89   19     89
```

How do I do this?

Comment: just rename the columns of `df_one` by `df_one.columns=['Jan','Feb','March']` or by using `rename()` method

Answer (score 2):

you can try using `apply`:

```
def func(row):
    y = df_one.loc[row.name]
    u = (dict(zip(row.values,y.values)))
    return u
res = pd.DataFrame(list(df_two.apply(func,axis=1)), index=df_two.index)
```

**res:**

|  | Jan | Feb | March |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 | 12 | 82 |
| 2020-01-02 | 5 | 15 | 85 |
| 2020-01-03 | 6 | 16 | 86 |
| 2020-01-04 | 7 | 17 | 87 |
| 2020-01-05 | 8 | 18 | 88 |
| 2020-01-06 | 9 | 19 | 89 |

map months `(Jan, Feb, March)`  with `values`

mapping will look like this:

```
{'Jan': 2, 'Feb': 12, 'March': 82}
{'Jan': 5, 'Feb': 15, 'March': 85}
{'Feb': 16, 'March': 86, 'Jan': 6}
{'Feb': 17, 'March': 87, 'Jan': 7}
{'March': 88, 'Jan': 8, 'Feb': 18}
{'March': 89, 'Jan': 9, 'Feb': 19}
```

using that you can create a dataframe.

Assuming both of them are having same indices and same size.

**One liner solution:**

```
res = pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(df_two.to_numpy()[idx], l)) for idx,l in enumerate(df_one.to_numpy())], index=df_one.index)
```

If you want to work on common indices.

```
i = df_one.index.intersection(df_two.index)
res = pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(df_two.loc[i].to_numpy()[idx], l)) for idx,l in enumerate(df_one.loc[i].to_numpy())], index=i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's use some pandas reshaping and concatenating methods:

```
df_one = df_one.rename(columns=dict(zip(df_one.columns, df_two.columns)))
df_out = df_one.stack().reset_index(name='value').merge(df_two.stack().reset_index(name='month'))
df_out = df_out.pivot('level_0', 'month', 'value').rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
            Feb  Jan  March
2020-01-01   12    2     82
2020-01-02   15    5     85
2020-01-03   16    6     86
2020-01-04   17    7     87
2020-01-05   18    8     88
2020-01-06   19    9     89
```

Details:

- First, lets get the column headers to match using rename, dict, and
  zip
- Stack each dataframe and reset_index creating common column headers
  to merge on
- Use pivot to reshape resulting dataframe

Comment: Hey Scott..How are you my friend? Kudos to you guys for understanding the question and giving such brilliant answers ...I'm literally having hard time understanding the question itself :-)

Comment: I just looked at the desired output and duplicated it using his inputs.

Answer (score 1):

It probably won't solve your problem if it is much more complicated, but it could be a starting point:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(df_one.apply(lambda x: [x[list(df_two.loc[x.name]=="Jan").index(True)],
                        x[list(df_two.loc[x.name]=="Feb").index(True)],
                        x[list(df_two.loc[x.name]=="March").index(True)]],axis = 1)),
             index = df_one.index,
             columns = ["Jan","Feb", "March"])
```

Output:

```
            Jan Feb March
2020-01-01  2   12  82
2020-01-02  5   15  85
2020-01-03  6   16  86
2020-01-04  7   17  87
2020-01-05  8   18  88
2020-01-06  9   19  89
```